# Graph count of items in a column with multiple items per row

Tags: powerbi, dax

Given this type of data:

[image]

Suppose I want to make two different graphs, one for the individual count of the items in the Order column and one for the Pets column. What would be the simplest way to do this?

Note that I want to graph the count of each item, and not group of items. This way I'd obtain a count of 4 - Burger, 2 - Pizza, and not 1- Burger, 1 - Pizza, Coke and so on.

Answer (score 0):

First count the number of burgers or pizzas etc. using custom column 'Pizza' using formula
`if (Text.Contains([Order],"Pizza")) then 1 else 0`.
Then write measures to sum the count.
`Measure_Pizza = SUM([Pizza])`

Then use measures in charts.

Alternate solution:

Write measures to directly calculate the count

`Pizza_count = CALCULATE (COUNT( Snacks_and_Pets[Order] ), FILTER(Snacks_and_Pets, FIND("Pizza", Snacks_and_Pets[Order], , 0 ) <> 0 )`